# how to work with iBatis

Tags: java, mysql, xml, netbeans-7, ibatis

I am so new in ibatis. I have read some feature on it and tried to work but it's not happening for me. May be I am facing placement problem here for xml files. Here is my work flow >>> I have taken a project in netbeans and keep ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar under Libraries package with Mysql JDBC Driver. Then I have created Employee.xml and SqlMapConfig.xml files and keep them under Web Pages/WEB-INF package. Then I have created Employee.java and IbatisInsert.java files and keep them under source packages/default-package folder. Now when I run IbatisInsert.java file it shows the following messages >>>

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not find resource SqlMapConfig.xml
>       at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:110)
>       at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:95)
>       at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.getResourceAsReader(Resources.java:161)
>       at IbatisInsert.main(IbatisInsert.java:20)

I am not understanding where to keep files and how to configure ibatis. I have searched google but not understanding. Can anyone please help me on this please ??!!! here are my xml files and java files belows :::

employee.xml >>>

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap 
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="Employee"> 
<insert id="insert" parameterClass="Employee">

   insert into EMPLOYEE(first_name, last_name, salary)
   values (#first_name#, #last_name#, #salary#)

   <selectKey resultClass="int" keyProperty="id">
      select last_insert_id() as id
   </selectKey>

</insert> 

</sqlMap>
```

SqlMapConfig.xml   >>>

```
    <!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/ibatisExample"/>-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
     <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
     <transactionManager type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
          <property name="JDBC.Driver" 
               value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"
               value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ibatisexample"/>
          <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
          <property name="JDBC.Password" value="123"/>
        </dataSource>
      </transactionManager>
     <sqlMap resource="Employee.xml"/> 
</sqlMapConfig>

<property name="JDBC.AutoCommit" value="true"/>

<property name="Pool.MaximumActiveConnections" value="10"/>

<property name="Pool.MaximumIdleConnections" value="5"/>

<property name="Pool.MaximumCheckoutTime" value="150000"/> 

<property name="Pool.MaximumTimeToWait" value="500"/> 

<property name="Pool.PingQuery" value="select 1 from Employee"/> 

<property name="Pool.PingEnabled" value="false"/>
```

employee.java >>>

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author sumon.bappi
 */
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String first_name; 
  private String last_name;   
  private int salary;  

  /* Define constructors for the Employee class. */
  public Employee() {}

  public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
    this.first_name = fname;
    this.last_name = lname;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
} /* End of Employee */
```

IbatisInsert.java   >>>

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author sumon.bappi
 */
import com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class IbatisInsert{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   throws IOException,SQLException{
   Reader rd = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
   SqlMapClient smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(rd);

   /* This would insert one record in Employee table. */
   System.out.println("Going to insert record.....");
   Employee em = new Employee("Zara", "Ali", 5000);

   smc.insert("Employee.insert", em);

   System.out.println("Record Inserted Successfully ");

  }
}
```

my file placement as like the following image >>>

[image: ibatis_file_placement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow reading **SqlMapConfig.xml** file , just put it under a *config* directory beside the *source* folder in the default package path and add the directory to your classpath.

Another thing i noticed you are missing in your **SqlMapConfig.xml** is the *mappers* .. The major role of this configuration file is to map the location of the xml resources as well as defining the data source parameters.

So you may need to add something like this at the end of your file:

```
<mappers>
      <mapper resource="PATH_TO_YOUR_DIR/Employee.xml />
</mappers>
```

Comment: It should work , make sure to add your folder to the classpath so that it reads it at runtime .. Can you show me the new placement of your files?

Comment: I have attached a image for your help. please notice it.

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer , you have to create a new folder call it **"config"** for example at the root level and copy your XML files inside it "Employee.xml" and "SqlMapConfig.xml" then add this folder to the classpath . This should fix the **"Could not find resource"** issue

Comment: okay, Please check if **SqlMapConfig** file exists in your bin or build folder and at which level?

Comment: it was fault on my xml file. I have deleted the property after </sqlMapConfig> tag and it works.

Comment: Ok great can you please accept my answer or upvote it if you think it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Place all xml files in same src folder where java file is there..
It will work